# ¿Por qué se usa una variable temporal en un for loop de C?

Tags: c, variables

Sigo sin entender cómo funciona, es decir, estoy intentando hacer un programa que calcule la potencia enésima de un número y he estado buscando ejemplos de como hacerlo pero me atasco en el for cuando se usa la variable temporal como contador, os pongo el código a continuación:

```
int Enesima()
 {
    int a, expo;
    float base, result;
    result = 1;


     printf("Introduce tu base:    ");
     scanf("%d", &base);

     printf("\n\n");

     printf("Introduce tu potencia:   ");
     scanf("%d", &expo);


     for(a = 1; a <= expo; a++) 
     {
         result = result*base;
     }

      printf("\n\n");


     printf("El resultado de %f ^ %d es %f", base, expo, result);


 }
```

`

No sé si mi entendimiento llega más lejos de que la variable temporal "a" es 1 al principio y que se le hace un incremento de 1 hasta llegar a la condición de ser menor o igual que el exponente, me gustaría una explicación más certera para entender de una vez el uso de una variable temporal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si nos vamos al concepto de potencia creo que quedará mas clara la idea de lo que hace el programa para obtener el resultado. Tomemos como ejemplo la operación **2^4**, en donde **2** es la base, y **4** el exponente. La misma operación la podemos definir de la siguiente forma:

2^4 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 16

Ahora, podemos también agregar lo siguiente:

2^4 = (1 * 2) * 2 * 2 * 2 = 16

En tu programa, la variable `a` llevará la cuenta de cuantas multiplicaciones se deben de llevar a cabo. La variable `resultado` almacenará lo que resulta de las multiplicaciones. La razón de que resultado se inicializa en 1 son dos razones:

1) Si se inicializara en `0` el resultado siempre sería cero:

(0 * 2) * 2 * 2 * 2 = 0

2) Si el exponente que se pasa a la función fuese `0` entonces la función regresa el valor de `1`. Recordemos que el resultado de elevar un número a la potenicia **0** es **1**

2^0 = 1

Comment: O sea, que "a" llevará la cuenta de las multiplicaciones la cantidad de veces necesaria hasta que llegue a la condición impuesta en el for, ¿no?Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: correcto.  Saludos

Comment: Muy bien, le seguiré dando al coco, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu ayuda.